# How to use MSBuild to build multiple platforms

Tags: msbuild, uwp, azure-devops, windows-store, windows-dev-center

I am using Visual Studio online build with an MSBuild task. I currently have the following MSBuild Arguments fed to my task:

```
/p:Configuration=Release;AppxBundle=Always;AppxBundlePlatforms="x86|x64|ARM";AppxPackageDir="$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\AppxPackages\\";UapAppxPackageBuildMode=StoreUpload
```

This creates my application in `x86`, `x64` and `ARM`. It creates Release version of the libraries in `x86` BUT creates Debug version of my libraries in `x64` and `ARM`.

When my `.appxupload` package is creates it fails Windows Certification tests because my libraries are built in debug.

How can I make MSBuild build for all 3 configurations. My guess is because I haven't provided a `/platform` configuration. How do I provide this configuration for 3 platforms?

I have tried `platform="x86|x64|ARM"` but it returned an error

Comment: It would be helpful if you could also list which version of MSBuild you are using and which version of the UWP SDK you are targeting.

Comment: Using Vs2017 MsBuild, targeting Windows 10 Anniversary Edition

Comment: Can you share the build log and the error you see from the WACK? (you can send me the details to rmpablos at ms dot com)

Comment: @rido it seems to be building in release now correctly. I think it was because I had ticked the `clean` for the task. Seemed to be producing `x86` in release and the other two in debug. very strange

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a standard project file there's no way to do this in a single command. Either use multiple commands to build the project for each platform/configuration combination needed, or use a 'master' build file which does the same for you, something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="FullRebuild">
  <Target>
    <ItemGroup>
      <Configurations Include="Debug;Release"/>
      <Platforms Include="x86;x64;ARM"/>
      <ConfigAndPlatform Include="@(Configurations)">
        <Platform>%(Platforms.Identity)</Platform>
      </ConfigAndPlatform>
    </ItemGroup>
    <MSBuild Projects="myproject.sln" Targets="Build"
             Properties="Configuration=%(ConfigAndPlatform.Identity);Platform=%(ConfigAndPlatform.Platform)"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: So to do this for Automated build I would probably need 3 MSbuild tasks with seperate configurations and then 1 task that would create my StoreUpload? Is that essentially what Visual Studio must do when you "Create a package for store"?

Comment: 1) yes, or as shown in the answer, one task which calls the MsBuild 3 times for you 2) Sorry, I don't know as I have no experience with that

Comment: UWP targets built the three platforms from a single MSBuild command

Comment: @rido yeah I'm not familiar with it; is the syntax really just /p:platform="a|b|c"?