# How do I integrate exe publishing with the VS2019 build of the console .net core 2.2 application?

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I saw a couple of similar questions but so far I found no single answer to the problem of integrating the publishing step with my build process. Unfortunately the dotnet publish command rebuilds the project again meaning that if I put the "dotnet publish" command in the project's Post-Build steps I get an infinite loop of building retries.

What I want to achieve is to get an exe built for my .NET Core 2.2 Console App for a few selected environments eg. osx and windows-10, possibly linux too, each in its own folder. Obvious condition is that it has to be integrated with the build, so no extra manuals steps (commands) are required. This has to work from within VS2019 Pro as well in CI (like AzureDevOps).

Is this basic step achievable or .Net core was a major step-back in the progress of software development?
I hope I just miss something and I am just grossly exaggerating. :)

Thanks, Radek

Comment: As you wanted to publish multiple times, a separate PowerShell script is a very common approach, https://github.com/lextm/restructuredtext-antlr/blob/v1.0.1/dist.server.ps1

Comment: Hi friend, can my workaround helps to resolve your issue for doing that in Azure Devops CI?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I integrate exe publishing with the VS2019 build of the console
>   .net core 2.2 application?

**Actually**, I think you do not need to worry about this.

`dotnet publish` already contains the build process. **Publish** process will first execute **Build** and then run publish. In a word, Build is  a part of Publish process.

So when you input `dotnet publish` under **Build**, you will get an infinite loop of building retries.

**Solution**

**-----** Just delete post-build event in `xxx.csproj` file and just `dotnet publish` directly and it will run the build process first.

You can test in the local VS and when you right-click on your project-->**Publish**, it will show the step in the output windwow.

**In addition**, as far as I know, Azure DevOps has a task called `dotnet publish` which contains Build.

[image]

**And** if you want to do some msbuild custom target only for publish step, you can add a condition like `Condition="'$(DeployOnBuild)'=='true'"`, it will execute for Publish process rather than the normal build step(right-click on your project-->Build).

```
<Target Name="testone" Condition="'$(DeployOnBuild)'=='true'" AfterTargets="Build">

    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx  

</Target>
```

**---------------Update 1----------------**

**First question**

**Actually**, the build of the publish is the pure process and then publish will copy the content of the build output into publish folder. So the execute program is just from the build output folder.

See the publish log:

[image]

So you should not specify a publish target under the build process. This is superfluous.

**Second question**

To generate this program for Window-10, linux or osx, you can try these command line to publish your project:(Release is the standard release build configuration)

For Win-10:

`dotnet publish -r win10-x64 -c Release --self-contained`

Linux:

`dotnet publish -r linux-x64 -c Release --self-contained`

For osx:

`dotnet publish -r osx.10.12-x64 -c Release --self-contained`

**In this way**, the project is first built according to the specified runtime and then published.

More info about .NET Core RID Catalog, you can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog).

**Update 2**

I think you should change the configuration in this package UI:

[image]

[image]

Then click **Save**.

Also, when you publish this web project, please try to delete bin and obj folder and then publish it.

**Debug**: `bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\publish`

**Release**: `bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\publish`

Or you should use dotnet command as I described to publish the project. The path is under Debug or Release folder.

Comment: That answers some parts of my question. Thanks a lot. I should however be more specific. I am looking for a solution that generates executable each time I press F5 (build). I tried to find a shortcut in VS2019 to assign it to publish action but there is no such action availabe. So I guess the only available is through post-build actions.

Comment: Another issue is that the Exe produced as Self-Contained .net-core 2.2 (Debug) publish action is not self-contained and cannot be run as there are missing dlls reported.

Comment: One more question I want to know is that whether your ouptut folder(`bin`) has some extra dlls. And please compare it with the publish folder and let me know it misses some dlls. It is just the information I want to confirm. And I will research your issue as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks @Perry Qian-MSFT. Ok, I think I found an issue. The Publish tab in VS2019 (Pro) does not update Target path upon change of Solution configuration (from Debug to Release and vice versa). That's why I was looking at bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\publish\ but it was actually in bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\publish\. I don't know if this is by design or not. Possibly not. Worth investigating. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> What I want to achieve is to get an exe built for my .NET Core 2.2
> Console App for a few selected environments eg. osx and windows-10,
> possibly linux too, each in its own folder. Obvious condition is that
> it has to be integrated with the build, so no extra manuals steps
> (commands) are required. This has to work from within VS2019 Pro as
> well in CI (like AzureDevOps).
>
> Is this basic step achievable or .Net core was a major step-back in
> the progress of software development?

It's a good idea but as I know what you want is not 100% supported for now.

**It seems that your expected scenario is:**

Click the Build(F5) button=>Project will be built in different platforms `win-x64,win-x86,linux-x64...`,also will be published in different platforms automatically with self-contained mode.

**But the fact is:**

1.Click the Build button(Build(F5) equals to the Build button in project context) will run the `Build` Target (A default built-in target for each project for build). => `dotnet build in command-line`.

2.Click the Publish button will run the `Publish` Target (A default built-in target for each project for publish). => `dotnet publish in command-line`.

[image]

3.If you have any `build/publish` command in post-build event, it will result in an expected loop. So it's hard to combine `publish` with `build` perfectly since they're two actions in VS with different button/behavior/corresponding command. (Only dotnet publish command can recognize `--self-contained`)

4.To build/publish the projects **in parallel**, the batch file or [msbuild targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-targets?view=vs-2019) file is a good choice.

`#1`.Build different platforms using one build command see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44434713/how-to-use-msbuild-to-build-multiple-platforms). `#2`.Publish different platforms using one command see [this](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/9363#issuecomment-387512008). (They both use custom .targets to do the job)

**Suggestions:**

According to your scenario, I think you can consider using #2. It's not necessary for you to build with different platforms during your normal development.

1.In local VS when you're developing and debugging:

The default build button/option is enough for you to debug.

2.In local VS when you want to publish the project in different platforms:

Use #2 above so that you can publish them using cmd.exe or PS.exe. (Via command `dotnet msbuild -restore -t:PublishAllRids`)

3.When you're automating the CI pipeline in AzDeops(Also use #2):

A CMD/PS task with `dotnet msbuild -restore -t:PublishAllRids` command is enough. Dotnet publish will build automatically if we don't pass `--no-build` argument.

4.Azure Devops Service suggests separate the jobs in different tasks, it's not recommend to Integrate Publish with Build heavily, especially for .net core projects. (Here's [official sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops#package-and-deliver-your-code) about CI for .net core projects.)